# Fit a quadratic function of two variables (Practitioner Black Scholes Deterministic Volatility Functions)

Tags: matlab, optimization, curve-fitting

I am attempting to fit the parameters of a deterministic volatility function for use in the practitioner Black Scholes model.

The formula for which I want to estimate the "a" parameters is:

sig = a0 + a1*K + a2*K^2 + a3*T + a4*T^2 + a5*KT

Where sig, K and T are known; I have multiple observations of K, T and sig combinations but only want a single set of "a" parameters.

How might I go about this? My google searches and own attempts all failed, unfortunately.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The function lsqcurvefit allows you to define the function that you want to fit. It should be straight forward from there on.

http://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html

Comment: Thank you - I had tried lsqcurvefit initially, but it appears there is only a single independent variable (xdata) or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Why does he need lsqcurvefit if his function is linear in a?

Comment: @SW7, the data variable may be a vector of values, such that your a's become xdata(1), data(2), etc..

Comment: @MatthewGunn He does not, but this solution was the one I found easiest, without any prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

#### Some Mathematics

Notation stuff: index your observations by i and add an error term.

```
sig_i = a0 + a1*K_i + a2*K_i^2 + a3*T_i + a4*T_i^2 + a5*KT_i + e_i
```

Something probably not insane to do would be to minimize the square of the error term:

```
minimize (over a)  \sum_i e_i^2
```

The solution to least squares is a simple linear algebra problem. (See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186196/understanding-linear-algebra-in-ordinary-least-squares-derivation/186289#186289 for a solution if you really care.) (Further note: e_i is a linear function of a. I'm not sure why you would need lsqcurvefit as another answer suggested?)

#### Matlab Code for OLS (Ordinary Least Squares)

Assuming `sig`, `K`, `T`, and `KT` are `n` by 1 vectors

```
y = sig;
X = [ones(length(sig),1), K, K.^2, T, T.^2, KT];
a = X \ y;  %basically computes a = inv(X'*X)*(X'*y) but in a better way
```

This an ordinary least squares regression of y on X.

#### Further Ideas

Depending on the distribution of your error terms, correlated error etc... regular OLS may be inefficient or possibly even inappropriate... *I'm not familiar with the details of this problem to know.* You may want to check what people do.

Eg. a technique that's less sensitive to big outliers is to minimize the absolute value of the error.

```
minimize (over a) \sum_i |a_i|
```

If you have a good, statistical model of how the data is generated you could do maximum likelihood estimation. Anyway... this rapidly devolve into a multi-quarter, statistics class.